# HttpServletRequest injection on RequestScoped bean CDI

Tags: java, jax-rs, httprequest, cdi, stateless

I'm looking for a way in order to inject a `@RequestScoped` custom class into my `@Stateless` JAX-RS endpoint:

I want each time the application receives a request my custom class is injected in my JAX-RS endpoint.

Custom class:

```
@RequestScoped
public class CurrentTransaction {

    private String user;
    private String token;

    @PersistenceContext(name="mysql")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Inject HttpServletRequest request;

    public CurrentTransaction() {
        this.user = request.getHeader("user");
        this.token = request.getHeader("token");
    }

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

So, I declare my `CurrentTransaction` class as `@RequestScoped` in order to be initialized each time a request is received.
In order to do this, I need to access to `HttpServletResquest` in order to get header parameters.

JAX-RS endpoint:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/areas")
public class AreasEndpoint {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mysql")
   protected EntityManager em;

   @Inject
   protected CurrentTransaction current_user_service;

    @POST
    @Path("postman")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Authentication
    public Response create(AreaRequest request) {

        if (this.current_user_service.getUser() == null) {
            System.out.println("Go!!!");
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
        } else {
            System.out.println("---- user: " + this.current_user_service.getUser());
            System.out.println("---- token: " + this.current_user_service.getToken());
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

CDI arrive to perform the constructor of `CurrentTransaction` class. However, `HttpServletRequest` request field is not initialized (injected).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you deploying to? Include versions.  Any stack traces would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late answer on this one--maybe useful to other readers: dependency injection in [CDI](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=346) is done in the following order:

1. the constructor is invoked
2. fields are injected
3. [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotated method is invoked

The last point is where you want to step in for further initialization that needs access on the injected fields:

```
@Inject HttpServletRequest request;

public CurrentTransaction() {
    // field injection has not yet taken place here
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // the injected request is now available
    this.user = request.getHeader("user");
    this.token = request.getHeader("token");
}
```

Comment: Do you suggest me to "inject" fields in `@PostConstruct`? Could you provide me any stuff helping code?

Comment: @user3227319 Please see my edit for the needed changes in code.