# How do I get hold of HTTP request headers in a CDI bean that's injected into a JAX-RS webservice?

Tags: java, jax-rs, httprequest, cdi

I have a web service like this:

```
@Path("/projects")
public class Projects {
    [...]

    @Inject
    CurrentRequest current;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response getProject(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        if (current.isUserAuthenticated()) {
            [...do something...]
        } else {
            [...produce an error...]
        }
    }
}
```

And a CDI bean with an auth checker method like this:

```
@RequestScoped
public class CurrentRequest {

    public boolean isUserAuthenticated() {
        [...do some header checking...]
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't for the life of me get hold of the HTTP headers from inside `CurrentRequest`. I tried injecting `HttpServletRequest`, but it's not initialized. I tried using `@Context`, same thing. Obviously `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` doesn't work either because there is no FacesContext.

I see that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047042/httpservletrequest-injection-on-requestscoped-bean-cdi) is basically asking the same thing, but hasn't received much attention.

My current approach is to use `@Context HttpServletRequest request` inside `Projects` and pass it as a parameter to `current.isUserAuthenticated(request)`. But that feels so wrong. Shouldn't the CDI bean know its own request?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

### Extracting the HTTP headers

You don't need the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) in your JAX-RS endpoints to get the HTTP headers from the request. Instead, you can inject [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html):

```java
@Context
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
```

Then you can use the [`HttpHeaders` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#method.summary) to get the header values:

- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getHeaderString-java.lang.String-)
- [`HttpHeaders#getRequestHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeaders--)
- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeader-java.lang.String-)

If you need the value of a standard HTTP header, consider using the [constants available in the `HttpHeaders` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#field.summary):

```java
// Get the value of the Authorization header
String authorizationHeader = httpHeaders.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```

### Using filters

Since you are performing authentication and/or authorization, I would recommend using filters, so you can keep your REST endpoints lean and focused on the business logic.

To bind filters to your REST endpoints, JAX-RS provides the meta-annotation [`@NameBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) and can be used as following:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

The `@Secured` annotation will be used to decorate a filter class, which implements [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), allowing you to handle the request.

The [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) helps you to extract information from the HTTP request (for more details, have a look at the [`ContainerRequestContext` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#method.summary)):

```java
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Use the ContainerRequestContext to extract information from the HTTP request
        // Information such as the URI, headers and HTTP entity are available
    }
}
```

The [`ContainerRequestFilter#filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html#filter-javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext-) method is a good place to abort the request if the user is not authenticated/authorized. To do it, you can use [`ContainerRequestContext#abortWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#abortWith-javax.ws.rs.core.Response-) or throw an exception.

The [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation marks an implementation of an extension interface that should be discoverable by JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase.

To bind the filter to your endpoints methods or classes, annotate them with the  `@Secured` annotation created above. For the methods and/or classes which are annotated, the filter will be executed.

```java
@Path("/")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response myUnsecuredMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is not annotated with @Secured
        // The security filter won't be executed before invoking this method
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Secured
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response mySecuredMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is annotated with @Secured
        // The security filter will be executed before invoking this method
        ...
    }
}
```

In the example above, the security filter will be executed only for `mySecuredMethod(Long)` because it's annotated with `@Secured`.

You can have as many filters as you need for your REST endpoints. To ensure the execution order of the filters, annotate them with [`@Priority`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Priority.html).

It's highly recommended to use one of the values defined in the [`Priorities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html) class (the following order will be used):

- [`AUTHENTICATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#AUTHENTICATION)
- [`AUTHORIZATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#AUTHORIZATION)
- [`ENTITY_CODER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#ENTITY_CODER)
- [`HEADER_DECORATOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#HEADER_DECORATOR)
- [`USER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#USER)

If your filter is not annotated with [`@Priority`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Priority.html), the filter will be executed with the [`USER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#USER) priority.

### Additional information

You'll probably find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227) useful.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me with the first part of your response - I _can_ get the headers in the JAX-RS class, just not directly in the CDI bean, hence my current approach of passing the HttpServletRequest to the bean. But I do like your idea of using Name Binding and annotations instead of an injected bean. I'll give it a go tomorrow and report back!

Comment: Haven't had time yet, sorry.

Comment: This answer did it for me ! Thanks.

Comment: And I am here waiting for @Antares42 to let us know if it was possible to inject the context directly on the EJB

Comment: In my case adding `@Context` was enough, it just take me some time since I was importing the wrong `HttpHeaders` class

Comment: @Ordiel - Back in EE6 I used a servlet filter to set up a user bean representing the client. Then after migrating to EE7 I changed that into a ContainerRequestFilter at the PreMatching stage. So I never got back to the original idea of accessing the HTTP headers from the bean.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the JAX-RS implementation and the server you are using, you might need some dependencies to provide integration between [CDI](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=346) and [JAX-RS](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339):

### [Jersey Ext Cdi1x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi/jersey-cdi1x)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### [RESTEasy CDI Integration Module](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-cdi)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

### [Apache CXF CDI Integration](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-integration-cdi)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-integration-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The project currently runs on EE6 with RESTEasy 3.0.4 and is deployed on an EAP 6.3. I also read here on SO that the injection should work out of the box in EE7, so I tried upgrading, but still got WELD errors on deploying. I'll try these integrators when I have time.

Comment: @Antares42 The Weld stacktrace will be useful. The injection of `HttpServletRequest` is supported out of the box in Java EE 7 (CDI 1.1). In Java EE 6 (CDI 1.0) you don't have this feature out of the box. What you can do is create a `ServletRequestListener`, store the `HttpServletRequest` in a `ThreadLocal` and create a CDI producer method for the `HttpServletRequest`.